# Reasons for high Memory Temperature?

Tags: temperature, sensors

I've installed `sensors` to measure the temperature of different parts of my machine. I did run `sensors-detect` and accepted all default options.

> I would like to know what **SODIMM** means, and whether this is natural behaviour (it being this hot). Also, what kinds of things can influence this (high memory usage?)

Here's the output (about 4 minutes after booting).

```
$ sensors
dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan: 1926 RPM
Processor Fan: 2132 RPM
CPU:            +36.0°C  
GPU:            +38.0°C  
SODIMM:         +46.0°C  

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +36.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +33.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +34.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +34.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +34.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

**P.S.:** I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Series.

Comment: just the definition of [SODIMM?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO-DIMM)

Comment: hmmm... and maybe some information regarding what to do about the temperature... I'll update thequestion

Comment: If you google the specific brand of your memory modules you will find a product sheet on them that includes normal operating temperature specifications.  Or you could just google "sodimm normal temperature" and look at a few different models.  You will find anywhere from `-40C` to around `80-90C` is fine.

Comment: With the above said if I saw my memory temp below 0 or above around 60 I would start looking into it more.

Answer (score 1):

If you really care to look into it further the best thing to do would be to set a baseline for your memory temperature.  You can create a script like the one below and set it to run as a cron job every 5-10 minutes for a day or two and then check your log for anomalies.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
templog="$HOME/templog"
now=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
temps=($(sensors | grep -E 'CPU|SODIMM' | tr -s " "))
cpuuse=$(top -bn2 | grep '%Cpu' | tail -1 | awk '{print 100-$8}')
mem=$(free -h | grep "Mem:" | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$7}')
echo "$now - ${temps[@]} CPU USE: $cpuuse% MEM USE: $mem" >> $templog
```

This will create a log file under `$HOME/templog` that has entries like such:

```
2017-08-10 03:37 - CPU: +36.0°C SODIMM: +46.0°C CPU USE: 8.5 % MEM USE: Mem: 1.0G 279M 744M 744M
```

You will want to make note of what your average temps are both while idle and under load and then establish what is normal for your machine.  This way you will be able to react if the tempuratures go outside your normal thresholds.

Comment: I like this. will try out for a couple days, then come back